# How to get the mode of Location when using FusedLocationApi in Android

Tags: java, android

I am using the following code to get the location of the user.

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
```

This returns me a `android.location.Location` object and I am successfully able to get the latitude and longitude however when I try to get the mode, it gives me "fused".

Whereas I want to know if the mode of getting Location was using GPS or Network.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for gps and network provider use following code.I don't think using fused api we are able to distinguish it

```
public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if(!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {

        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;

            if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    if (location != null) {

                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }

            }

            if(isGPSEnabled) {
                if(location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    if(locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                        if(location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the using accuracy. If the accuracy is high, it is from GPS.